# Get Build Job URL in TeamCity Build Step

Tags: teamcity

I have a Microsoft Teams webhook which will alert me when a TeamCity build has failed. I am wondering how I would be able to get the URL of the current TeamCity build so I can pass this information to my webhook.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only using parameters at hand, you could build the uri back to the build log:
`%teamcity.serverUrl%/viewLog.html?buildId=%teamcity.build.id%`

If you're using a MessageCard, this would make the `potentialAction` field of the payload to something like:

```json
"potentialAction": [
    {
        "@type": "OpenUri",
        "name": "View in TeamCity",
        "targets": [
            {
                "os": "default",
                "uri": "%teamcity.serverUrl%/viewLog.html?buildId=%teamcity.build.id%"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Anything fancier would require a call to the [TeamCity REST API](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/rest-api.html)