# How to put a hyperlink in a MS Teams message sent from a Powershell script in a TeamCity build project?

Tags: html, json, powershell, teamcity, microsoft-teams

I'm using TeamCity to build my project.
In one of my build steps, I put a Powershell script, which uses Webhook to send a message to a MS Teams channel.

```
$url = "https://..."
$body = @{
    title = "MtTitle";
    text = "Visit: $url";
} | ConvertTo-Json
$postBody = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetByres($body)
Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri "https://mycorp.webhook.office.com/..." -Body $postBody -ContentType "application/json" -UseBasicParsing
```

As a result of the script above, a message is sent to the Teams channel as expected, but the URL (the string after `Visit:`) is shown as a plain text.
How is it possible to make it a clickable hyperlink?
Should I use a MessageCard as shown in the link below?
[Get Build Job URL in TeamCity Build Step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63179541/get-build-job-url-in-teamcity-build-step)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a link in teams like that:

```
[HereText](hereLink)
```

Code would look somthing like that:

```
$url = "https://..."
$urlText = "some"
$body = @{
    title = "MtTitle";
    text = "Visit [$urlText]($url)";
} | ConvertTo-Json
Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri "https://mycorp.webhook.office.com/..." -Body $postBody -ContentType "application/json" -UseBasicParsing
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for! Thank you very much for your help.